# how to use loop for return or push value in filter pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

i create filter pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class filterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(model: any[], query: number): any[] {
     return model.filter(listProductCatalog =>
        (listProductCatalog.items[0].quotaFlg == 'Y' || listProductCatalog.items[1].quotaFlg == 'Y' )

      );
}}}}
```

i need to know how to create loop(or something) for return model.filter listProductCatalog.items[i]
because sometime items have more 0,1. value for the same product catalog

```js
 value for the same product catalog

{
    "listProductCatalog": [
        {
            "level1": "APPLE",
            "level2": "IPAD
RETINA 16GB",   "priceIncAmt": 40000,   "items": [{    "listSubItem":
[
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPAD4 16 GB",
            "color": "WHITE",
            "stockQty": 100,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "Y",
            "tradeFlg": "Y"
        },
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "color": "BLACK",
            "stockQty": 6,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "level1": "APPLE",
    "level2": "IPAD RETINA 64GB",
    "priceIncAmt": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "color": "BLACK",
            "stockQty": 5,
            "unitAmt": 0,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "color": "WHITE",
            "stockQty": 4,
            "unitAmt": 0,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "Y",
            "tradeFlg": "Y"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "level1": "APPLE",
    "level2": "IPAD RETINA 32GB",
    "priceIncAmt": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPAD4 32 GB",
            "color": "BLACK",
            "stockQty": 3,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "Y",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "color": "WHITE",
            "stockQty": 15,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "Y"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "level1": "APPLE",
    "level2": "IPAD MINI 64GB",
    "priceIncAmt": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPAD MINI64GB",
            "color": "WHITE",
            "stockQty": 10,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPAD MINI64GB",
            "color": "BLACK",
            "stockQty": 7,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "level1": "APPLE",
    "level2": "IPHONE 4 16GB",
    "priceIncAmt": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "groupMatNo": "PD1302003143",
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "HANDSET",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPHONE4 16GB",
            "color": "WHITE",
            "stockQty": 3,
            "unitAmt": 1,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
            "listSubItem": [
                {
                    "priceIncAmt": 0
                }
            ],
            "productType": "DEVICE",
            "productSubtype": "HANDSET",
            "brand": "APPLE",
            "model": "IPHONE4 16GB",
            "color": "BLACK",
            "stockQty": 7,
            "unitAmt": 0,
            "stepQty": 1,
            "quotaFlg": "N",
            "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
    ]
}
]
}
```

sorry for my english

thank you for help

Comment: do you want only items to be returned? or the entire listProductCatalog?

Comment: i need entire listProductCatalog

Comment: Sure, so to confirm you want all listProductCatalog whose items quota flag is "Y" right? can you provide a sample data, so that I can help better? can a product catalog have more than one item and what if one of it has "Y" and the other "N" or a different value for the same product catalog? Is that possible?

Comment: i will edit  to topic

Comment: Sorry I can not sort, it alert "it look like your post is mostly code"

Comment: so given your sample, the apple ipad retina 16gb contains two `listSubItems` with one `Y` and the other `N`, given this would you want this in your filtered list or not?

Comment: i want only listSubItems == 'Y' , like this
https://imgur.com/v8gFJ3N


if can't ,i want the apple ipad retina 16gb both like this
https://imgur.com/jbWp5gU

Answer (score 0):

One could use a map and filter function in js. Assuming you want to return only items, here is how you do it. Read about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on MDN.

```js
  var jsonStr = "{\"listProductCatalog\":[{\"level1\":\"APPLE\",\"level2\":\"IPAD RETINA 16GB\",\"priceIncAmt\":40000,\"items\":[{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPAD4 16 GB\",\"color\":\"WHITE\",\"stockQty\":100,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"Y\",\"tradeFlg\":\"Y\"},{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"color\":\"BLACK\",\"stockQty\":6,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"}]},{\"level1\":\"APPLE\",\"level2\":\"IPAD RETINA 64GB\",\"priceIncAmt\":0,\"items\":[{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"color\":\"BLACK\",\"stockQty\":5,\"unitAmt\":0,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"},{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"color\":\"WHITE\",\"stockQty\":4,\"unitAmt\":0,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"Y\",\"tradeFlg\":\"Y\"}]},{\"level1\":\"APPLE\",\"level2\":\"IPAD RETINA 32GB\",\"priceIncAmt\":0,\"items\":[{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPAD4 32 GB\",\"color\":\"BLACK\",\"stockQty\":3,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"Y\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"},{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"color\":\"WHITE\",\"stockQty\":15,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"Y\"}]},{\"level1\":\"APPLE\",\"level2\":\"IPAD MINI 64GB\",\"priceIncAmt\":0,\"items\":[{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPAD MINI64GB\",\"color\":\"WHITE\",\"stockQty\":10,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"},{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"SPECIAL PRODUCT\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPAD MINI64GB\",\"color\":\"BLACK\",\"stockQty\":7,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"}]},{\"level1\":\"APPLE\",\"level2\":\"IPHONE 4 16GB\",\"priceIncAmt\":0,\"items\":[{\"groupMatNo\":\"PD1302003143\",\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"HANDSET\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPHONE4 16GB\",\"color\":\"WHITE\",\"stockQty\":3,\"unitAmt\":1,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"},{\"listSubItem\":[{\"priceIncAmt\":0}],\"productType\":\"DEVICE\",\"productSubtype\":\"HANDSET\",\"brand\":\"APPLE\",\"model\":\"IPHONE4 16GB\",\"color\":\"BLACK\",\"stockQty\":7,\"unitAmt\":0,\"stepQty\":1,\"quotaFlg\":\"N\",\"tradeFlg\":\"N\"}]}]}"

     var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
     var result = json.listProductCatalog
                 .reduce((a, b)=> a.concat(b.items.filter(i => i.quotaFlg === 'Y')), [])
                 .map(j => `${j.brand || ''} ${j.color || ''} ${j.model || ''}`);

     console.log(result);
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jayas_godblessall/wg3h01ej/

*Something along these lines, feel free to modify, like if you want the entire object remove the `map` from above, just made sure I captured your result seen on your image right*

Answer (score 0):

**Here it is, this is how you can do it :**

```
var resultData = model.listProductCatalog.filter(listProductCatalog => {
    listProductCatalog.items = listProductCatalog.items.filter(item =>     {
        if(item.quotaFlg === 'Y'){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return listProductCatalog.items.length > 0;
});
```

OR Shorter Version :

```
var resultData = model.listProductCatalog.filter(listProductCatalog => {
    listProductCatalog.items = listProductCatalog.items.filter(item => item.quotaFlg === 'Y');
    return listProductCatalog.items.length > 0;
});
```

**Please run the below snippet and check the console for the output :**

```js
var model = {
  "listProductCatalog": [
    {
      "level1": "APPLE",
      "level2": "IPAD RETINA 16GB",
      "priceIncAmt": 40000,
      "items": [
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPAD4 16 GB",
          "color": "WHITE",
          "stockQty": 100,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "Y",
          "tradeFlg": "Y"
        },
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "color": "BLACK",
          "stockQty": 6,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level1": "APPLE",
      "level2": "IPAD RETINA 64GB",
      "priceIncAmt": 0,
      "items": [
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "color": "BLACK",
          "stockQty": 5,
          "unitAmt": 0,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "color": "WHITE",
          "stockQty": 4,
          "unitAmt": 0,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "Y",
          "tradeFlg": "Y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level1": "APPLE",
      "level2": "IPAD RETINA 32GB",
      "priceIncAmt": 0,
      "items": [
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPAD4 32 GB",
          "color": "BLACK",
          "stockQty": 3,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "Y",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "color": "WHITE",
          "stockQty": 15,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "Y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level1": "APPLE",
      "level2": "IPAD MINI 64GB",
      "priceIncAmt": 0,
      "items": [
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPAD MINI64GB",
          "color": "WHITE",
          "stockQty": 10,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "SPECIAL PRODUCT",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPAD MINI64GB",
          "color": "BLACK",
          "stockQty": 7,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "level1": "APPLE",
      "level2": "IPHONE 4 16GB",
      "priceIncAmt": 0,
      "items": [
        {
          "groupMatNo": "PD1302003143",
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "HANDSET",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPHONE4 16GB",
          "color": "WHITE",
          "stockQty": 3,
          "unitAmt": 1,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        },
        {
          "listSubItem": [
            {
              "priceIncAmt": 0
            }
          ],
          "productType": "DEVICE",
          "productSubtype": "HANDSET",
          "brand": "APPLE",
          "model": "IPHONE4 16GB",
          "color": "BLACK",
          "stockQty": 7,
          "unitAmt": 0,
          "stepQty": 1,
          "quotaFlg": "N",
          "tradeFlg": "N"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var resultData = model.listProductCatalog.filter(listProductCatalog => {
    listProductCatalog.items = listProductCatalog.items.filter(item =>     {
        if(item.quotaFlg === 'Y'){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return listProductCatalog.items.length > 0;
});

console.log(resultData);
```